# How many shares for Udhiyyah can a large animal have?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunni, udhiyyah

On a large animal, is there a minimum share that it is allowed to be split by for Udhiyyah purposes.  I heard somewhere that a large animal can have 7 shares.  Is this the max?  Authentic sunni sources would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sheep is only one share.  While a Camel, a Cow, or a Buffalo can have 7 shares.

> Narrated Jabir bin ‘Abdullah : We performed tamattu' during the
>   lifetime of the Messenger of Allah (), sacrificed a cow for seven and
>   a camel for seven people. We shared them.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ حَنْبَلٍ، حَدَّثَنَا هُشَيْمٌ، حَدَّثَنَا
>   عَبْدُ الْمَلِكِ، عَنْ عَطَاءٍ، عَنْ جَابِرِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ،
>   قَالَ كُنَّا نَتَمَتَّعُ فِي عَهْدِ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   نَذْبَحُ الْبَقَرَةَ عَنْ سَبْعَةٍ وَالْجَزُورَ عَنْ سَبْعَةٍ
>   نَشْتَرِكُ فِيهَا ‏.‏

[Sunan abi Dawood](http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/16/20)

Now, if there are seven people who want to slaughter for nearness (القربة) than it is right, but if one of the seven just wants to slaughter for the meat than the Udhyyah is not accepted from all of the seven.

Source: Al fiqh Al Muyyassar Ala Mdhab al Imam Al A'tham Abu Hanifah Anna'man ( الفقه الميسر على مذهب الإمام الأعظم أبو حنيفة النعمان)